# Typescript error after compile Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to build an app using NodeJs. I'm familiar with raw Node.JS but Typescript is new.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, well, to get it running but I keep running into this error after it compiles into Javascript again. `Cannot set property "title" of undefined`

So I have two classes, a base class that looks like :

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';

export class BaseRoute {

    public basePath: string; // this gets set in child constructors
    public title: string;
    private scripts: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.title = "";
        this.scripts = [];
    }

}
```

And the one who inherits looks like this:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, Router } from 'express';
import { BaseRoute } from './BaseRoute';

export class IndexRoute extends BaseRoute {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.basePath = "/";
    }

    index(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        this.title = "Home | Page";
        let options: Object = {
            "message": "This is a test message"
        };

        this.render(req, res, "index", options);
    }

}
```

It transpiles fine into Js but when I try to go to the route `/` I get the error. The stack tells me that it's being thrown in `IndexRoute.index`

The transpiled version looks something like:

**BaseRoute:**

```
"use strict";
var express_1 = require("express");
var BaseRoute = (function () {
    function BaseRoute() {
        this.title = "";
        this.scripts = [];
    }
    return BaseRoute;
}());
exports.BaseRoute = BaseRoute;
```

**IndexRoute:**

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var express_1 = require("express");
var BaseRoute_1 = require("./BaseRoute");
var IndexRoute = (function (_super) {
    __extends(IndexRoute, _super);
    function IndexRoute() {
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.basePath = "/";
        return _this;
    }
    IndexRoute.prototype.index = function (req, res, next) {
        this.title = "Home | Page";
        var options = {
            "message": "This is a test message"
        };
        this.render(req, res, "index", options);
    };
    return IndexRoute;
}(BaseRoute_1.BaseRoute));
exports.IndexRoute = IndexRoute;
```

Comment: Let me guess: You use `app.use(route.index)` somewhere.

Comment: More precisely, `this.app.use(route.basePath, route.getRoutes());`. Judging by how you phrased it, I'm going to assume that this was a poor choice ?

Comment: Sorry for being rude. No, this doesn't seem to be a bad choice. But the error you see must come from some similar issue (you know, javascript and it's unusual `this` keyword). Can we see more of the code? What does `route.getRoutes` do?

Comment: Not to mention, how did the call to `render` not cause a type error? It's not declared in the derived class or in the base class. Question needs a minimal self-contained repro.

Comment: Right, it should cause a compilation error in TypeScript. I have missed that.

Comment: Right, sorry, I had to reduce the code to meet the stackoverflow question standards. `getRoutes()` returns a `express.Router` instance. The purpose of this is to mimic the standard way of doing this where file `routes/index.js` would have `module.exports = router`. The purpose of this is so I can do `app.use('/users/', require('./routes/users'))`

Comment: Thanks Tamas, due to your suggestion about the JavaScript `this` in `app.use` I was able to successfully debug my program by moving the router as a property of the `BaseRoute` instead of returning a `express.Router` instance from `getRoutes`. If you want to go ahead and submit an answer I would be willing to mark it as the answer